# Fine-tune a model with larger input size

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, computer-vision

I was wondering does it make sense to fine-tune a model with larger input size? Ideally, the properties I would like to have:

1. Fine-tune: meaning reuse the weights by pre-training
2. Larger input size: Not down-sampling before feeding in the model. Maybe have a larger stride size?

Specifically I'm trying to fine-tune InceptionV3 in Keras with my specific label set. I want a larger data size since I hope the model can implicitly learn some important characters. With InceptionV3 default size (`299x299`) this doesn't sounds possible to me.

But that sounds like I have to change the specific model that I'm re-using (say by modifying specific layer in [model architecure](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/master/keras_applications/inception_v3.py)), then re-using pre-trained weights doesn't make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fine-tune a classification model usually you would remove a few of the top layers, which acts as the classifier, and add your own layers. This is the same with fine-tuning the Inception_V3 model: you can remove the top layers and add your own classifier with the desired number of units (i.e. number of classes in your dataset). For example:

```py
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3

# let's say our images are of size (1000, 1000, 3)
inc_v3 = InceptionV3(include_top=False, input_shape=(1000, 1000, 3), pooling)

# add your desired layers to the top
# we only add one layer just for illustration
# but you can add as many layers as you want
out = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(inc_v3.output)

# construct the new model
model = Model(inc_v3.input, out)
```

However, note that you need to first freeze all the base layers (i.e. layers of Inception_V3 model) for fine-tuning. Further, instead of adding a pooling layer at the top (i.e. `pooling='avg'`), you can also use other alternatives such as using a `Flatten` layer.

Further, I recommend you to read the relevant official Keras tutorial: [Building powerful image classification models using very little data](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html) (the second and third sections are mostly relevant to this).

Comment: Thanks for your replace. I understand the need of replacing top layer with my own classification head. However, it seems for dealing with larger input size, you simply specify a larger input_shape? No need to modify, say, the first few layers (close to input) in InceptionV3? This is the part that I'm not sure.

Comment: @clwen No, it is not needed because the base of Inception consists of convolution, pooling and batchnorm layers which does not depend on the width and height of input image.